# Why consistent linear system with $n$ variables and $n-1$ equations will have infinite amount of solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Repeating the question from the title

> Why consistent linear system with $n$ variables and $n-1$ equations
>   will have infinite amount of solutions?

The proposition can be verified by hand when $n$ is small, for example $n = 2$

We will have something like

$$a_{1}x + a_{2}y = s_{1}$$
and $x$ will equal to:

$$x = \frac{s_{1} - a_{2}y}{a_{1}}$$

And since $y$ can take on any value, we conclude that we have inf. amount of solutions

Although a bit more lengthy, it can be shown that the proposition holds for $n = 3$ too. But now my question is: how do we show that the proposition holds for any $n$ ($n ≥ 2$ and $n \in \mathbb Z$)?

Comment: Do you know about row-echelon form? It explains everything about solutions to systems of linear equations.

Comment: I say, DO YOU KNOW ABOUT ROW-ECHELON FORM?

Comment: @Gerry, I'm sorry, I do. I looked up a proof using rref, but it wasn't very clear to me. In a nutshell, it went like this: If there are more variables than non-zero rows, then we have column that doesn't have leading one and thus there is at least one variable that can take on infinitely many values. However, the explanation wasn't very clear to me. If you have better (perhaps more intuitive) alternatives that involve rref, I would be glad to see them. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Hope it helps.

Comment: You've had three answers, and nothing to say about any of them. Have you lost interest, Nelver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see it is that you can use one of the equations to express a variable in terms of the others, use that to eliminate that variable and discard the used equation. If you keep on doing that, you'll end up with one equation and two variables, thus you can select the value of one of them and that determines the other one. I.e., there are infinite solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you don’t want to entry in Analytic Algebra realm, you can see that if the system is consistent then you can consider one of the $n$ variable (call it $x$) as a constant and solve the system as one that have $n-1$ variables for $n-1$ equation... at the end every variable could be expressed in terms of $x$ and so (always by the fact the system is consistent) at least one variable will have infinitely many values (for example $x$).

Answer (score 0):

Consider an augmented matrix in reduced row-echelon form. Each column corresponds to a different variable (except the last column, where the constants live). A column that has a leading $1$ in it will be called a *pivot column*, and the corresponding variable will be called a *pivot variable*. A variable that isn't a pivot variable will be called a *free variable*.

There may be one or more all-zero rows. As the system is assumed to be consistent, each such row corresponds to the equation $0=0$, which is no restriction on the solutions, so we can ignore any such row. So, from here on, we assume each row has a leading $1$.

Every row then looks like this:$$\pmatrix{0&0&\dots&0&1&*&*&\dots&*&|&*\cr}$$ where the asterisks in pivot columns are all zero but the other asterisks may be nonzero. Every such row stands for an equation of the type, $$\text{pivot variable equals linear combination of free variables, plus constant}$$ The free variables, if there are any, can be given arbitrary values; the equations then determine the values of the pivot variables, and give a solution to the original system of equations. So, if there are any free variables at all, then the system will have infinitely many solutions.

If there are $n$ variables and $n-1$ equations, then there can be at most $n-1$ leading $1$s, so at most $n-1$ pivot variables, so there must be at least one free variable, hence, infinitely many solutions.